# Windows form design advice

Tags: c#, winforms

I have built a touch screen application using Windows Forms.
It works great but I still would like to have some design advice.

My application consists of several different windows forms.

My design is that I have one MainForm which all of the other forms inherit from. In this Mainform I have the buttons where the user can choose which form to open.
When the user chooses one of the options another form is opened. I use the following code:

```
Control control = this;                // the current form, that is open
Recording rec = Recording.Instance;    // the form that the user choose to open
if (control != rec) {
    rec.Show();                        // show the recording form 
    control.Hide();                    // hide the previous form
}
```

Is this a correct way to work with forms or should I use some other way? For example, have one form and user controls in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things I noticed:

1. `Recording.Instance`.  That looks to me like you are making these forms singleton.  That can work, but I'd rather see them created/closed as needed.
2. `rec.Show();` This is a nitpick, but a lot of the time you want to pass the current form as an owner:  `rec.Show(this);` or `rec.Show(control);`.
3. Inheriting a base form is good.  To make it work even better, also build each form as a custom control, such that the only difference among your forms is which custom control you've added.  You can also use an interface or common base control for each of these custom controls for further control and enforce a uniform look and feel in your app.

Comment: Thanks for the help, some clarification:<br />1

Comment: Thanks for the help, some clarification: 1) Yes I use singleton. I thought this would be the best for performance. That way I don't have to create and close the form all the time. 2) What is the reason for this? 3) Thanks for the tip

Comment: Sorry for the messed up text, I haven't figured out how to do a new row in comments :)

Comment: Singleton probably won't help performance much, and might actually hurt it because you'll have to keep a bunch of old forms around in memory that you're not using.  Reason for #2 is that it sets the owner property of your form. It lets you do a few things on how a child form relates to a parent.

Answer (score 1):

This method works, but depending on your application you could have some issues with this long term.

The main area of potential concern is that doing "control.Hide();" keeps the instance of the control in memory, as long as you are ok with this behavior, you are fine.

Comment: I used the Hide intentionally. In my mind this would be better performance wise. I only have five forms in this application and none of the "eats up memory". But I'm very glad to here what is "the correct way to do it." This works now but maybe not in a future applicaton?

Comment: With 5 forms, that should be just fine.